# EXTJS: How can i upgrade my Sencha EXTJS 5.0.1 application to EXTJS 5.1.1 version?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I want to upgrade my current application which was built in EXTJS 5.0.1 version with Sencha CMD 5.0.1 .
Can somebody please provide the exact steps needed to upgrade it to Sencha EXTJS 5.1.1 version ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can update your framework using:

```
sencha app upgrade /path/to/sdk
```

Afterwards you can update the app using:

```
sencha app upgrade -ext
```

> In most cases, you will need to perform a build on your application
>   before everything begins working as expected. This can be done by
>   executing the following commanad [[sencha](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cmd_upgrade_guide.html)]

```
sencha app build
```

Comment: Thanks All above..  but i receive error when i do above command "sencha app upgrade /pathtonewframeworkSDk"  as it says the Sencha CMD version being used is not the one intended/supported by the upgradeTO framework .   **[ERR] Sencha Cmd version (5.1.1.39) is incompatible with required version (5.1.3.61-5.1.3.61)**

Comment: So [update your `cmd` version](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/cmd-download/)...

Comment: Thanks ..we upgraded to Ext6.x version now with CMD 6 :)